# onClick not firing on first click, works as expected from second click onwards

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, onblur

I have an input field and a button placed below it.

```
// onClick associated with the button.

onClick={() => {
    alert('Button clicked');
}}>
```

The input field has `onBlur` associated with it.

```
blurHandler = event => {
        if (undefined !== event) event.stopPropagation();
        var inputObj = document.getElementById('myInputId');
            if ((inputObj.checkValidity())) {
                this.setState({ariaInvalidState : "false"})
            } else {
                if(inputObj.value !== "") {
                    this.setState({isInputEmpty : false})
                    this.setState({ariaInvalidState : "true"})
                } else {
                    this.setState({ariaInvalidState : "false"})
                }
            }
        if (typeof this.props.onBlur === 'function') this.props.onBlur(event);
    };
```

The first click on the button is not showing the alert msg. From 2nd click it's working as expected.

What's causing this?

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: You have a syntax error in your code `var inputObj = document.getElementById('myInputId);`. You missed the closing quote.

Comment: @Alexandr Thanks. Corrected that. I missed the closing quote while removing the original id value.
The issue is still there.

Comment: Could you show all code of the component? It is not yet clear what could have gone wrong and what does `blurHandler` have to do with it. =)